# Vector field with numpy and mathplotlib

Tags: python, vector-graphics

I know how to generate a vector field in all plane, but know I'm trying to create the vector just in some specific line, my code is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3,3,15)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,15)

x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
u = x
v = (x-y)


plt.quiver(x,y,u,v,color = "purple")
plt.show()
```

that create the vector field in all plane, but I want the vector field along the line x=y, how should I do that?

To create a line, with x1 and y1 for example, and change x,y for x1,y1 in u,v

Answer (score 0):

For the case along the line x=y, you can define the coordinates as follows:

```
X = np.linspace(0,9,10)
Y = np.linspace(0,13.5,10) 
U = np.ones(10)
V = np.ones(10) 
  
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, color='b', units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(-2, 15)
plt.ylim(-2, 15)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]